# Standalone asio async_connect not firing off bound handler

Tags: c++, ssl, asio

I have followed the [documentation and examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/client.cpp) provided by the boost asio implementation but not having any luck after connecting my client to the server. Regardless of success or failure, the handler is never called. I have verified that the server is receiving and accepting the connection from the client but nothing happens on the clients end to indicate success.

```
void ssl_writer::main_thread() {
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    using namespace asio::ip;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
    tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.170.115", "8591");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpointer_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    io_context.run();

    std::cout << "connecting...";
    asio::async_connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpointer_iterator, std::bind(&ssl_writer::handle_connect, this, _1));
}

//...

void ssl_writer::handle_connect(const std::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
        std::cout << "connected!";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "failed!";
    }
}
```

Comment: In wrong place you are calling `io_context.run()` it should be after `async_connect`. Inside `io_context.run()` completed handlers are called.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. If you would, put this into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io_context::run()` processes handlers until there are no more handlers to process. As you haven't yet run any asynchronous calls there are no handlers and `run` returns immediately.

In this simple example you need to call `io_context::run()` after `async_connect`, in more complex programs you would normally create a worker thread to call `io_context::run()` and create an instance of `boost::asio::executor_work_guard` to prevent the `io_context` running out of work.